# Bind a model to Radio Button in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model

```
 public class SexModel
 {
    public SexModel()
    {

        this.Man = "Man";
        this.Woman = "Woman";
        this.ManId = 1;
        this.WomanId = 2; 
        this.WomanSelected = this.ManSelected = false;
    }

    public bool ManSelected { get; set; }
    public bool WomanSelected { get; set; }
    public string Man { get; set; }
    public string Woman { get; set; }
    public int ManId { get; set; }
    public int WomanId { get; set; }

 }
```

create a radio button on my view

```
 @Html.RadioButton(Model.Man,  Model.ManId, Model.ManIsSelected, 
                   new { @id = Model.ManId})


 @Html.RadioButton(Model.Man, Model.WomanId, Model.WomanSelected,
                   new { @id = Model.WomanId })
```

user can select man or woman radio buttons on register form, but why always WomanSelected and ManSelected  are both false after click submit form button in my action?

Comment: Use `Html.RadioButtonFor` instead, like so: `Html.RadioButtonFor( m => m.ManIsSelected, Model.ManId)`. Though can you please explain what `Model.Man` and `Model.Sex.Man` are?

Comment: sorry i edited to Model.man it was an mistake.i change it to   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.ManSelected,Model.ManId, new { @class = "radio" }) but it did not works

Comment: `SexModel` - best class name yet +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be binding your radio buttons in MVC via [RadioButtonFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.radiobuttonfor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) i.e.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ManSelected, m.Man);
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.WomanSelected, m.Woman);
```

Comment: my action is   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(SexModel sexModel) is it correct? with your solution not works yet I'm confused :)

Comment: @motevallizadeh yep looks ok to me. Do you also have `public ActionResult Index() { return View(new SexModel()); }`? Post your controller...

Comment: yes i have it   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SexModel ff = new SexModel();
            return View(ff);
        }