# Html.RadioButtonFor MVC Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, radio-button

My view has one string property.  Doing a get request through an action result and sending to view -- it looks like this:

```
public ActionResult TeaCoffeView(string teaOrCoffee)
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    //do some stuff
    //teaOrCoffee has two values , if "T" i have
    //to make the view as tea radio button selected 
    //or if it has "C" then coffee radio button selected 

    return View(model);
}
```

my view .cshtml

```
@Html.Label("tea:")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m._teaOrCoffee, Model._teaOrCoffee)  
@Html.Label("coffe:")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m._teaOrCoffee, Model._teaOrCoffee)
```

Model

```
public string _teaOrCoffee {get; set;}
```

How to bind the value with `@Html.RadioButtonFor` so that when loads it should show as selected?

Comment: You probably meant `return View(model);` in the controller action, right?

Comment: yes @granit  - correct

Comment: Please see the answer I added.

Comment: You may check these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852821/how-can-i-bind-a-radio-button-with-model-data-in-asp-net-mvc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389610/bind-a-model-to-radio-button-in-asp-net-mvc4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the second argument in `@Html.RadioButtonFor()` to set the value for which it should be selected.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model._teaOrCoffee, "T") @Html.Label("tea:")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model._teaOrCoffee, "C") @Html.Label("coffe:")
```

Comment: can you please see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43518802/dropdownlistfor-to-be-auto-selected-on-the-basis-of-a-value-of-string-asp-net-mv too