# DropdownListfor to be auto selected on the basis of a value of string asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have one string and one list proeprty in my model

```
public string  _drinkType { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> _drinkTypeDropDown { get; set; }
```

in my view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m._drinkTypeDropDown , new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem{Text="Milk", Value="1"},
    new SelectListItem{Text="coffee", Value="2"},
    new SelectListItem{Text="tea", Value="3"}
}
```

Now in my controller , I am getting the the value "Milk" , "tea" and "coffee"  in the property `_drinkType`. I have to set the selected option in `DropdownlistFor` when it matches with the property value

somewhat like 
`if _drinktype  = milk`
then dropdownlistFor will be loaded automatically with Milk selected

Comment: A dropdownlist binds to the `Value` property. Your `_drinkType` property needs a value of `1` for `Milk` to be selected (or use change the code to set the `Value` to `Milk`)

Comment: i can change it in controller  , can you explain with code please

Comment: Either `new SelectListItem{Text="Milk", Value="milk"}` **or** set `_drinkType = 1`

Comment: can you please explain with code

Comment: What do you think the last 2 comments contain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a `ViewBag` property with the possible options in the controller and the model can keep only the property which will hold the actual value. In your controller, add the value to `ViewBag`:

```
ViewBag.DrinkTypeDropDown = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem{Text="Milk", Value="1"},
    new SelectListItem{Text="coffee", Value="2"},
    new SelectListItem{Text="tea", Value="3"}
};
```

In your, declare the drop down list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model._drinkType, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DrinkTypeDropDown)
```

**Edit**: Since you have the `Text` property and the selected option will be selected if there is a match in the `Value` of `SelectedListItem`, you could add a property in your model:

```
public string _drinkTypeValue { get; set; }
```

Before returning the view from the controller action result, you would have to set the `_drinkTypeValue` based on the value of `_drinkType`:

```
model._drinkTypeValue = model._drinkTypeDropDown.Where(item => item.Text == model._drinkType).FirstOrDefault().Value; // You will have to treat null values of FirstOrDefault() here
```

In your view, bind the drop down value to the `_drinkTypeValue`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model._drinkTypeValue, Model._drinkTypeDropDown)
```

When the user submits the form, it will actually submit the `_drinkTypeValue` so you will have to convert it again to `_drinkType` in a similar fashion.

Comment: cant use viewbag , tempdata , viewdata anything  . is there any other way

Comment: Just use a ViewModel instead of ViewBag then.

Comment: @tripathy The `ViewBag` is just a suggestion, please see my editted answer.

Comment: OP is already generating the options. This does not answer the question!

Comment: @StephenMuecke OP was binding the wrong property to the drop down list i.e. `_drinkTypeDropDown` which would only be used to keep the options. Anyway, another problem was the fact that the intention was to select the value of drop down based on the `Text` property of the `SelectedListItem`, so I edited my answer to handle that.

Comment: That will never bind to anything when the form is submitted!

Comment: @StephenMuecke correct, but If we add the setter, it will be submitted as `_drinkTypeValue`. Depending on what would be needed after submission, OP could retreive the `_drinkType` from `_drinkTypeValue` again as well. I assume this is intentional, otherwise I would have handled it differently by using enumerations.